# How to implement a sectioning feature in html

Tags: html, css

How can I implement something in html that can separate sections, for a example, a simple line...

Section 1:
BLAH BLAH BLAH

---

Section 2:
BLAH BLAH BLAH

Because as of now, my html just looks like this:

Section 1:
BLAH BLAH BLAH

Section 2:
BLAH BLAH BLAH

I've used `<br>` but I think it would look a lot better if there was an actual separator of some sort.

Comment: Use <hr>. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just used `hr` in your post.
 
this is another way to do it.

HTML:

```
<span class="section">Section 1: BLAH BLAH BLAH</span>
<span class="section">Section 2: BLAH BLAH BLAH</span>
```

CSS:

```
.section{
    border-bottom:1px solid gray;
}
.section:last-child{
    border-bottom:0px;
}
```